# Trying to change login page from mysql_connect to work with PDO, with no luck

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to change my login page from mysql_connect(which work's perfectly) to work with PDO, with no luck.
Every time i hit 'login' with a correct username and password it just refresh the same login page.

Thanks in advance!

**Working code with mysql_connect:**

```
<? 
    session_start();
    $user = "XXXX";
    $password = "YYYY";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div align="center"><h1>Home</h1>
    <h3>
      <? if (isset($_SESSION["authenticated"])) { ?>
        You are logged in!  
        <br />
        <a href="logout.php">log out</a>
        <a href="userpage.php">See page</a>
      <? } else { ?>
        You are not logged in!
      <? } ?>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <?
        if (($connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $password)) === false)
            die("Could not connect to database");

        // select database
        if (mysql_select_db("123456", $connection) === false)
            die("Could not select database");

        // if username and password were submitted, check them
        if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
        {
            // prepare SQL
            $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='%s'",
                           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]));

            // execute query
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if ($result === false)
                die("Could not query database");

            // check whether we found a row
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                // fetch row
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                // check password
                if ($row["password"] == $_POST["password"])
                {
                    // remember that user's logged in
                    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = true;
                    $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
                    $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/\\");
                    header("Location: http://$host$path/userpage.php");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </form></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**New code with PDO(doesn't work):**

```
<? 
    session_start();
    $user = "XXXX";
    $password = "YYYY";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=123456', $user, $password);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div align="center"><h1>Home</h1>
    <h3>
      <? if (isset($_SESSION["authenticated"])) { ?>
        You are logged in!  
        <br />
        <a href="logout.php">log out</a>
        <a href="userpage.php">See page</a>
      <? } else { ?>
        You are not logged in!
      <? } ?>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <?
        // if username and password were submitted, check them
        if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
        {
            // prepare SQL
            $idd = $_POST["name"];
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='$idd'";
            $result = $dbh->query($qry);

            if ($result === false)
                die("Could not query database");

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) === false)
                die("No luck!");

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                // fetch row
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                // check password
                if ($row["password"] == ($_POST["password"]))
                {
                    // remember that user's logged in
                    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = true;
                    $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
                    $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/\\");
                    header("Location: http://$host$path/userpage.php");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </form></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use try---catch for db connection to check where you are getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `mysql_`* functions on a PDOStatement object returned by the query method. To get the number of rows try `$result->rowCount()`. To fetch the record use one of the fetch methods. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: Oh my god!! thank you!!! you just helped me with a problem I struggled with for the last 4 days. Thank you so much!